# MediaLibrary.SavePicture method results in a System.UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I've got the following code which handles downloading and saving an Image to the phone's media library. It fails with a `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` as if there was some cross-thread access. To my understading all code below an await statement runs on the UI thread so this should not be an issue. In addition I've tried wrapping the code below `var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(this.Url);` with `Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` but it did not help. :(
I am running this on WP8 with the intention to port the code later to WP7.

```
    private async void OnSaveImageCommand()
    {
        RunProgressIndicator(true, "Downloading image...");
        var client = new WebClient();
        try
        {
            var stream = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(this.Url); 

            var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(stream);

            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
                writeableBitmap.SaveJpeg(memoryStream, writeableBitmap.PixelWidth, writeableBitmap.PixelHeight, 0,
                                         100);
                memoryStream.SetLength(memoryStream.Position);
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary(); 
                mediaLibrary.SavePicture("image.jpg", memoryStream);
                MessageBox.Show("Image has been saved to the phone's photo album");
            }
        }
        catch 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to download image"); 
        }
        finally
        {
            RunProgressIndicator(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you add an ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO capability to your app's manifest?

[image: ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO]

UnauthorizedAccessException is 99% of the time a missing capability.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the capability fixed it.