# Take a screenshot programmatically when My App is loaded

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to take a screen shot when My App is loaded, without any user interaction.

My code is like this

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(ApplicationBarIconButton);

    }

    private void ApplicationBarIconButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var fileName = String.Format("WmDev_{0:}.jpg", DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        WriteableBitmap bmpCurrentScreenImage = new WriteableBitmap((int)this.ActualWidth, (int)this.ActualHeight);
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Render(LayoutRoot, new MatrixTransform());
        bmpCurrentScreenImage.Invalidate();
        SaveToMediaLibrary(bmpCurrentScreenImage, fileName, 100);
        MessageBox.Show("Captured image " + fileName + " Saved Sucessfully", "WmDev Capture Screen", MessageBoxButton.OK);

        currentFileName = fileName;
    }

    public void SaveToMediaLibrary(WriteableBitmap bitmap, string name, int quality)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.
            bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

[image]

Comment: on which line does the exception occur?

Comment: at... new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);

Comment: have you added ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO capability to app's manifest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387294/medialibrary-savepicture-method-results-in-a-system-unauthorizedaccessexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14387294/medialibrary-savepicture-method-results-in-a-system-unauthorizedaccessexception

Answer (score 3):

This article on the Nokia developer wiki explains how you can capture **your app's** screen programmaticaly (you can find an extensive code sample as well):

http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_capture_screen_programmatically_in_Windows_Phone_7

There is no API that allows you to take a screenshot of the **whole** screen from inside your app (such as taking a capture of another app for instance).

**Regarding that error** you show us in the picture, it seems your app might not have authorization to save the picture in the MediaLibrary.

Try placing the code in the method SaveToMediaLibrary inside a try-catch block:

```
    public void SaveToMediaLibrary(WriteableBitmap bitmap, string name, int quality)
{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
           // Save the picture to the Windows Phone media library.
           bitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, bitmap.PixelWidth, bitmap.PixelHeight, 0, quality);
           stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
           new MediaLibrary().SavePicture(name, stream);
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
        {
          // log the exception message, uae.Message, in your favourite way :)
        }
    }
}
```

If the exception occurs on the call to SaveLibrary(), as shown in [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/a99aff6e-dbec-47ac-9e96-e0c5a5d90650/i-am-getting-unauthorized-access-exception-while-saving-image-to-medialibrary?forum=wpdevelop) on msdn, in the **first answer**, you need to specify the Media Library Capability in your app manifest, like this: ID_CAP_MEDIALIB

I hope this helps.

Comment: The code Sriram showed us was taken from that article :)